# I am trying to modify the content of an HTML element using external Javascript with getElementById but it is not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

My javascript file is web-scraping data from a website and returning the good answer. However, it looks like the HTML file is not updating the information. Can someone point me in the right direction on what is going wrong? In my HTML file, I am making sure that `<script src="scrape1.js">` is at the end of the body paragraph.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function getPrice(){

    let URL= 'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/synthetix-network-token';
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL, {waitUntil: 'load'});

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {

        try {
        let price=document.querySelector('div[class="text-3xl"] > span').innerText;
            return {
               price
            }
    
        }catch(err) {
        reject(err.toString());
        }})
    
        variable=Object.values(data)[0];
        console.log(variable);
    
    
        await page.evaluate(data => {
        
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    
            const element = document.getElementById("snxprice");
            element.innerHTML = Object.values(data)[0];
        
            });
        
         }, data)

     
     
    await browser.close();

})().catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log(element)` after element to your code and see what is returned in the console

Comment: It does not print anything. From what I understood is that everything that is run inside the page.evaluate function is done in the context of the browser page not in node.js.